# How to detect transition from one shape to another in V8?

Tags: javascript, v8

Let's say I have next code:

```js
let x = null;
x = 10;
```

How I can detect shape transition here? From NULL_TYPE to SMI ?
I know that there should be some built in function. [Here](https://gist.github.com/totherik/3a4432f26eea1224ceeb) is the list.

I expect that it will be possible to run `node --allow-natives-syntax` or smth like that, for instance:

```js
let x = null;
x = 10;
console.log(%DetectTransition(x))
```

Comment: `%DebugPrint` logs some useful details

Comment: @JonasWilms In both cases (with and without transition) I\m receiving same result:`Smi: 0xa (10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

There is no shape transition in that code snippet, as the concept "shape" only applies to objects.

Here is an example with a shape transition:

```
let a = {x: 1};
let b = {x: 1};
%HaveSameMap(a, b);  // true
b.y = 2;
%HaveSameMap(a, b);  // false
a.y = 3;
%HaveSameMap(a, b);  // true
```

`%HaveSameMap` compares the shape descriptors of the provided objects and returns `true` or `false`. For a lot more detail, you can also use `%DebugPrint` as @JonasWilms suggested.

Of course, we're talking about internal details here (both what happens under the hood, and how you can inspect it for debugging or curiosity purposes). Nobody is making any promises that things will continue to work in exactly this way. (I think the basics are unlikely to change, but the details do change.)

Comment: let's say we have `let x = {a: null}; x.a=1`. Is this code is perfectly fine? I mean from optimization point of view?

Comment: Yes, sure. The property doesn't care whether its value is `null` or `1`. (Of course, in that specific snippet, it'd be more efficient to just write `let x = {a: 1}`, but that's probably not what you're asking, and in the big scheme of things a single assignment doesn't matter anyway.)